# Apply rolling as part of a column calcuation?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to create a new column that finds the minimum offset value (i.e. number of rows back) of the minimum value in a specific window, only problem is the window size changes from row to row.

A way to find the minimum offset value from the current row using a static number, is to reverse the order of the column, and then apply the argmin function with a shift, like so:

```
df['initx1'] = df['Close'][::-1].rolling(20).apply(np.argmin, raw=True).shift(-(20 + 1))
```

...however, what I'd like to do is use a dynamic rolling number without having to resort to using a for loop, I want this done as a column calculation like the above. The psuedo-code of what I'm attempting looks like this:

```
df['initx1'] = df['Close'][::-1].rolling(df['dynamicWindowSize']).apply(np.argmin, raw=True).shift(-(df['dynamicWindowSize'] + 1))
```

...but of course it throws an error saying rolling should be an integer, even though the series in df['dynamicWindowSize'] ARE all integers, but I know it's because I'm passing in a series. Any ideas?

A reproducible dataset and code is provided below to work with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create a reproducible, static dataframe.
# 1 minute SPY data. Skip to the bottom...
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:30",
        "open": "457.2",
        "high": "457.29",
        "low": "456.78",
        "close": "456.9383",
        "volume": "594142"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:31",
        "open": "456.94",
        "high": "457.07",
        "low": "456.8",
        "close": "456.995",
        "volume": "194061"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:32",
        "open": "456.99",
        "high": "457.22",
        "low": "456.84",
        "close": "457.21",
        "volume": "186114"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:33",
        "open": "457.22",
        "high": "457.45",
        "low": "457.2011",
        "close": "457.308",
        "volume": "294158"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:34",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.4",
        "low": "457.25",
        "close": "457.32",
        "volume": "172574"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:35",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "396668"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:36",
        "open": "457.48",
        "high": "457.6511",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "186777"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:37",
        "open": "457.5699",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.5699",
        "close": "457.69",
        "volume": "187596"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:38",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.54",
        "close": "457.63",
        "volume": "185570"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:39",
        "open": "457.63",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.59",
        "volume": "164707"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:40",
        "open": "457.59",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.7199",
        "volume": "167438"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:41",
        "open": "457.72",
        "high": "457.8",
        "low": "457.68",
        "close": "457.72",
        "volume": "199951"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:42",
        "open": "457.73",
        "high": "457.74",
        "low": "457.6",
        "close": "457.62",
        "volume": "152134"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:43",
        "open": "457.6",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.5077",
        "volume": "142530"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:44",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.4001",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "122575"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:45",
        "open": "457.61",
        "high": "457.76",
        "low": "457.58",
        "close": "457.75",
        "volume": "119886"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:46",
        "open": "457.74",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "183157"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:47",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "128542"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:48",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "154181"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:49",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.5898",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "163063"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:50",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.59",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.555",
        "volume": "96229"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:51",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.61",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.4217",
        "volume": "110380"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:52",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "107518"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:53",
        "open": "457.475",
        "high": "457.51",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.48",
        "volume": "78062"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:54",
        "open": "457.49",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.46",
        "volume": "133883"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:55",
        "open": "457.47",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "98998"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:56",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.43",
        "close": "457.43",
        "volume": "110237"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:57",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.375",
        "close": "457.65",
        "volume": "98794"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:58",
        "open": "457.66",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.35",
        "close": "457.45",
        "volume": "262154"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:59",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.47",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.4",
        "volume": "74685"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:00",
        "open": "457.41",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "166617"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:01",
        "open": "457.39",
        "high": "457.7",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.5",
        "volume": "265649"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:02",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.53",
        "volume": "131947"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:03",
        "open": "457.53",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "80111"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:04",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.62",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.6101",
        "volume": "117174"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:05",
        "open": "457.621",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.51",
        "close": "457.58",
        "volume": "168758"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:06",
        "open": "457.58",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "84076"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:07",
        "open": "457.62",
        "high": "457.7401",
        "low": "457.62",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "125156"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:08",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.67",
        "volume": "116919"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:09",
        "open": "457.69",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "102551"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:10",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.56",
        "close": "457.7",
        "volume": "109165"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:11",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.725",
        "low": "457.63",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "146209"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:12",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.88",
        "low": "457.64",
        "close": "457.86",
        "volume": "210620"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:13",
        "open": "457.855",
        "high": "457.96",
        "low": "457.83",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "159975"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:14",
        "open": "457.95",
        "high": "458.02",
        "low": "457.93",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "152042"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:15",
        "open": "457.96",
        "high": "458.15",
        "low": "457.96",
        "close": "458.08",
        "volume": "146047"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:16",
        "open": "458.085",
        "high": "458.17",
        "low": "457.99",
        "close": "458.15",
        "volume": "100732"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:17",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.33",
        "low": "458.155",
        "close": "458.245",
        "volume": "235072"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:18",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.29",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.16",
        "volume": "422002"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:19",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.2801",
        "low": "458.1699",
        "close": "458.28",
        "volume": "114611"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:20",
        "open": "458.29",
        "high": "458.39",
        "low": "458.24",
        "close": "458.37",
        "volume": "241797"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:21",
        "open": "458.37",
        "high": "458.42",
        "low": "458.31",
        "close": "458.345",
        "volume": "124824"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:22",
        "open": "458.33",
        "high": "458.49",
        "low": "458.33",
        "close": "458.47",
        "volume": "132125"
    }
])

# Convert df to numeric and time to datetime re: the .csv to .json
# converter tool I used online...
df[['open','high','low','close','volume']] = df[['open','high','low','close','volume']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# Define an initial x1 value. This is the minimum offset index number for the min
# of the last 20 rows. So, looking at the previous 20 rows, INCLUDING the current
# one, if the minimum close value happened 5 bars ago, this number would be 5.
# If the current bar holds the lowest close over the last 20 bars, this number
# would be 0. This is not important to the question as this part works as is.
df['initx1'] = df['close'][::-1].rolling(20).apply(np.argmax, raw=True).shift(-(20 + 1))

# Part of the strategy I'm wanting to emulate requires to get the second last initx1
# value and to add 2 to that number, so that's what I'm doing here
df['x1'] = df['initx1'].shift(2) + 2

# 'dynamicWindowSize' is called 'x2' and is just 1 + x1
df['x2'] = df['x1'] + 1

# To mitigate the error "trying to set rolling on an empty sequence" later,
# just drop nan rows from x1 and x2 now. Will only be the top 20 rows anyway.
df = df.dropna(subset=['x1', 'x2'])

# Convert x2 to integer
df['x2'] = df['x2'].astype(int)

# Inspect
print(df)

# This is the pseudo code of what I want. It doesn't work now obviously,
# but the rolling window size just needs to be the value in x2 for each
# row
df['lfOffset'] = df['close'][::-1].rolling(df['x2']).apply(np.argmin, raw=True).shift(-(df['x2'] + 1))

# # I found an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955008/python-pandas-rolling-mean-with-window-value-in-another-column
# # that I tried modifying for my purposes here, but also doesn't work.
# def get_lfOffset_min(x):
#     win = df.loc[:,'x2'].iloc[x.shape[0]-1].astype('int')
#     win = max(win, 0)
#     return pd.Series(x).rolling(window = win).apply(np.argmin, raw=True).shift(-(win + 1)) #.mean().iloc[-1]
# df.loc[:,'lfOffset'] = df.loc[:,'close'].expanding().apply(get_lfOffset_min)
```

Comment: why don't you try .rolling(int(df['dynamicWindowSize']))

Comment: @tdy Yes it is a similar concept, but that agg function with lambda stuff is a little over my head so I'm not sure how to make that work here?

Comment: @deirdreamuel `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: so df['dynamicWindowSize'] is not an integer but a series. On the code you have, you only have 'open','high','low','close','volume', and time. How are you setting  df['dynamicWindowSize']?

Comment: Yes as the question says, I'm not trying to use a static number, I want to base the column calculation on the values in the 'dynamicWindowSize' column, which for this purpose can be assumed is a bunch of random integers. If you need, use this to generate a column of random numbers:

`data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=len(df))

df['dynamicWindowSize'] = data`

Comment: I tried you sample code `df['initx1'] = df['Close'][::-1].rolling(20).apply(np.argmin, raw=True).shift(-(20 + 1))` and I got this at index 26, `26 2021-10-26 09:56:00  457.5100  457.5400  457.4300  457.4300  110237     8.0`. The value at column intx1 is 8.0. How 8.0 is calculated? I do not understand this `that finds the minimum offset value (i.e. number of rows back) of the minimum value in a specific window`. Could you explain more about this? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly, all that line is doing is finding the "offset value" of the previous minimum value within a window. So for example, let's say you're currently on row 50, and your "rolling window" is set to 20, that means the number it will return will be 50 - argmin of rows 30 to 50. So if the minimum Close value happened 8 bars ago, that's where the 8 comes from. It's just the number of rows back from the current row that the minimum value happened, but only looking back 20 rows or so. What I want now, is to use those values in another column's rolling function...

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example of an input dataframe, including the `dynamicWindowSize` column? If you could also provide the desired output, computed by hand for a small dataframe, even greater.

Comment: @Anton I have updated my code above to provide a full working example, and it is well commented. I'm just looking to create a new column called "lfOffset" which uses the values in column "x2" in its rolling calculation. So the rolling number/x2 changes row by row, it's not just a static number. I want to do this without using a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally one can not look at two columns inside of the window function (the function supplied to `.apply()`). Since Pandas 1.3 there is an exception: if one uses Numba and specifies `method="table"`, the whole dataframe is passed to the function. It is passed as an array, which makes the code somewhat ugly, but it does the job.

```py
import numba
import math

@numba.njit
def compute_offset(arr):
    window_size = arr[-1, 1]
    min_ = math.inf
    min_idx = None
    window_start = max(arr.shape[0] - window_size, 0)
    
    for i in range(arr.shape[0] - 1, window_start - 1, -1):
        if arr[i, 0] < min_:
            min_ = arr[i, 0]
            min_idx = i
            
    result = np.empty(3)
    result[:2] = arr[-1, :2]
    result[2] = arr.shape[0] - 1 - min_idx  # the offset
        
    return result

offset = (
    df[["close", "x2"]]
    .assign(offset=-1)
    .expanding(method="table")
    .apply(compute_offset, raw=True, engine='numba')
    .offset
)

df_processed = df.join(offset)
```

Here are the first 20 rows of the result computed from the provided input:

[image]